# Win32::Process::KillProcess not returing proper exitcode

Tags: perl

I am writing a function in perl which will kill a process given its PID.

```
sub ShutPidForWindows()
{
    require Win32::Process;
    $PID = 1234;
    $count = 0;
    $ReturnStatus = 0;
    $ExitCode = 0 ;

    if ($PID == 0)
    {
        return ($ReturnStatus);
    }

    Win32::Process::KillProcess($PID, $ExitCode);
    print "PID = ".$PID."\n";
    print "Return Code = ".$ExitCode."\n";

    if ($ExitCode)
    {
        $ReturnStatus = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $ReturnStatus = 2;
    }
    return ($ReturnStatus);
}
```

when this function is executed it always returns `2`. Even though the process `1234` does not exists.

The o/p I get is:

```
PID = 1234
Return Code = 0
```

Perl Doc says that `ExitCode` will be populated by the exit code returned by the process. Then `ExitCode` should be `1`.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Why do you think the exit code should be `1` if the process doesn't exist? If there is no process there can be no problem exit code and the value of `$ExitCode` is irrelevant.

Comment: @Borodin Even if the process exists the ExitCode is not changed. if i initialize ExitCode to say -1 it remains -1 after KillProcess (even if the process exists). What i see is that KillProcess is not returning proper ExitCodes.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;` in your perl code. And when passing arguments to a function, receive in this manner `my($arg1, $arg2, @garbage) = @_`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `require` instead of `use` to load the module. Sometimes this is OK, but you should always follow the examples in the module's documentation.

You must also *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program you write. This will make it necessary to declare all of your variables, which should be done as close as possible to their first point of use. These measures will reveal many errors that you may otherwise overlook, and is especially important when you are asking others for help with your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you examine [`$^E`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#%24%5EE) after the call to `Win32::Process::KillProcess`, you might see a value like

```
The parameter is incorrect
```

which should tell you that you did something wrong.